# Difference between SPWeb and SPSite

Tags: document-library, powershell

What is the difference between SPWeb and SPSite?
I have this code using SPWeb

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite 
ForEach($list in $web.Lists)
{
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
    {
        Write-Host $list.Fields
        if($list.Fields.ContainsField("marking") -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "found" $list.Title
        }
    }
}
```

Which doesn't produce the right result, as apparently GPMS marking is not a column for a Document Library.
But when I use this code using SPSite

```
Get-SPSite mysite |
Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary"} |
Select -ExpandProperty Fields |
Select Title | out-file test.txt
```

This has the so called marking column that I want to search for in the previous bit of code.
Is there anyway of changing the previous bit of code so it does find the marking column?

Comment: SPSite represents a _site collection_ while SPWeb represents a specific web site within the site collection. Normally, you open a specific SPWeb within SPSite via SPSite.OpenWeb(). You can use SPSite.AllWebs to enumerate existing webs, or SPSite.RootWeb.

Comment: So your site name is same for both the cases??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to start of with the tree ;)

You have a farm (SPFarm) and in that farm you have many web applications (SPWebApplication), within one of those web applications you would have a site collection(SPSite) and within that site collection you would have many sub sites (SPWeb) that hold many sites (SPWeb) or in your case webs (SPWeb) under the site colleciton.

from a url perspective:

```
http://webApplication(SPWebApplication)/siteCollection(SPSite)/web(SPWeb)
```

coding wise in your case your calling an spweb on a toplevel spsite. coding wise if you want to get the spweb object you need to note that its rootweb ;) as your mysite is based at the sitecollection and not at the subsite or site level!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.rootweb.aspx

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://mysite
$site.RootWeb.Lists
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is a bit ambiguous. One example deals with just 1 SPWeb at a specific location, the other with an SPSite, as you say, but you pipe ALL the subwebs of that SPSite (and even subwebs within subwebs I believe). So it may be that you find the field in a completely different SPWeb under the SPSite, where before you were just checking 1 specific SPWeb under the SPSite.

So most likely that field was not deployed to "http:// skynet" but a different SPWeb.